# PHP thumbnail generator - a movable rectangle

Tags: php, gd

I'm kind of an beginner programist and i want to create a PHP thumbnail generator. I already know how to resize and crop images using PHP and i wrote a thumbnail generator that generates thumbnails using the same resize sizes and crop sizes for the every image in the folder. Here is my idea: firstly, user has to point the folder containing images to make thumbnails of and specify thumbnail's height and width and secondly, display the image with a movable rectangle (transparent, but with visible border) of the given thumbnail's x and y on it so the user would be able to choose which area of the image to crop. I know how to do the cropping and apply the proper variables and operations, my only problem is to do the drawing part. I know there are functions like imagepolygon but no idea how to make them movable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use javascript for that, something like : http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html